# Using thin wire with a breadboard

Tags: wire, breadboard

I want to insert a wire into my breadboard for prototyping, however the wire is thin so it folds and frays when I try to push it into an open slot.

Is there a particular type of pin I need to use in order bridge the gap?

Comment: You talk about the wire "fraying" it sounds like you are using stranded wire. You really need to use solid wire.

Answer (score 0):

Because of what it is (a friction-fit prototyping array) you really need to use the wire that was intended for it. This will prevent frustrating fallouts, partial connections, etc.

[These kits are available all over the place](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005GYB93M), so save yourself some frustration.

Here is a related question with more details:
[What gauge of single strand wire works well with breadboards?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31675/what-gauge-of-single-strand-wire-works-well-with-breadboards)