# Soldering cheesy 9 V battery wires to wires I can plug into my breadboard

Tags: batteries, wire, breadboard

I have a wire that fits atop my 9 V battery and it should easily feed into a breadboard but it does not as the wire is stranded.

I tried last week to solder these wire strands to [breadboard jumper wires](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011GGCBQW) so I could feed them into my bread board, but they just don't allow current to flow through; this did not work despite my efforts and even using heat shrink.

Is there a component that would do this better or some soldering technique I should be using instead?

Comment: Show a photo of your crime.

Comment: Cheese is a poor conductor of electricity. You should consider using copper battery wires.

Comment: Lee, are you just saying you wish you had [one of these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtv1q.png)?

Comment: @jonk For sure!

Comment: if forced to guess I'd say the wires or the breadboard are damaged.

Comment: @Jasen No I didn't jam them in the breadboard...I soldered them together with a pair of stiff wires like you'd normally jam into a breadboard.

Comment: @leeand00 You can buy them already done up like that. Or, you can peal back the top side thin plastic on your 9V connector and cut the stranded wire away from there and replace it with solid wires and then superglue the plastic *toupee* back together, again. Screwing around with a solid wire and stranded wire joint in the middle just leaves you with a weak joint that will cause no end of trouble.

Comment: @jonk Sweet I'll give it a try.

Comment: You can also solder the stranded wires to a couple pins of a 2.54mm/0.1" pitch header and plug that into the breadboard. Use some heat shrink to increase the bend radius at the solder's edge if you want it to last.

Comment: @Transistor I'll send you a photo when I can find it.  I really need to buy a lighter as I've done heat shrinking before, but it didn't turn out to well this time given that I didn't have a lighter.

Comment: Heatshrink is an insulator. That will have no effect on conductivity other than preventing short circuits. It's your soldered joint that is the problem or the type of wire you have selected. What are the "hard wires" made of? They should be copper. If you can't solder to them with resin-cored solder and a decent, hot enough soldering iron then you've got something else.

Comment: You could get any used battery disassemble it and use the Top part. Then weld wires to any + 16V electrolytic capacitor (radial is better), wind and solder the flexible wire on the capacitor terminals. This provides two features: (1) gives you 2 “rigid” wires for  polarized connection on the breadboard, and (2) provides you a filtering capacitance to lower internal resistance and make 9V more stable, being useful in +90% of the circuits you may assemble. Cost: negligible, Fun: see how a 9V battery is made inside.

Comment: You can use the barrel of a soldering iron to do the heat shrink if you don't happen to have a proper temperature-controlled heat gun.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yeah that's what I tried to do; wait till you see my picture.

Comment: This looks good didn't know it was a thing.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/217671/2956

Comment: @leeand00  I know what you mean and many EE's also do. BUT some don't. A photo of your stranded wire would help.

Comment: Best to follow other better advice in comments :-) - BUT - scrape stranded wire until oxide free. Solder strands with lots of solder fed in and MAYBE some NONACID flux until SOME solder adheres properly - the more the better. THEN wrap stranded wire around jumper tip and solder with lots of solder until it takes. Cover with heat shrink or tape to hide the mess and prevent shorting. It works, BUT best not done at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I connect small stranded wire to solid wire so I can plug it in to a breadboard.

[image: Joint]

Note that the stranded wire, in your case the wire from the battery, is wrapped around the sold wire about 5 mm from the end of the solid wire. With heat shrink around the assembly, this will support the stranded wire against the solid wire so the stranded wire won't break when flexed.

Be sure that the soldering flux is removed from the exposed solid wire as the flux will cause poor electrical contact in the breadboard. Isopropyl alcohol will remove the flux.

If you are using cheap breadboards, you will have problems with high resistance connections due to the poor quality of the contacts in the breadboard.